# Free Alternatives to Edge for Epub

Tags: ebooks, epub

Can someone suggest EPUB file format Readers WITH options to Annotate text in PC?

I have been using Microsoft Edge for a really long time. So, it is tragic that it shall end its support as EPUB Reader.
So can I get recommendations for alternative softwares with-

1. **User-friendly interface** like Edge.(This is the most difficult criteria, I think)
2. Has options to Annotate/Bookmark/etc Text
3. I don't know how to phrase this but opening epub files thru Edge works significantly faster than opening the same epub file with
       another app from the Microsoft Web Store. So, can I get something similar?

I have tried Calibre, Icecream Book Reader, Kindle for PC, Adobe Digital Editions, Kobo but am not really satisfied. I know I am asking for a lot, but can someone help me.

Comment: I love using Edge as EPUB reader too as it is simple yet get the job done nicely. I had been hunting one for long to the point why not put some time in research and write one. This is THAT hard to find a good alternative of Edge.